# How would I output the number of odds and evens in register #0x40?

Tags: assembly, 8051

Not sure how I would initialize the contents of #0x30 through #0x39 into #0x40 and #0x41. I know that I should have 7 evens and 3 odds. I tried making a Loop2 that would move R1(#0x30) into R5(#0x40), but I'm
not sure if that's correct, as I feel that there is a much easier way to implement the odd and evens into register #0x40. Also please don't reference the code at the very beginning as that was just some baseline code for me to reference from. Not looking for someone to do the work for me, but some hints or tips would be helpful as I'm pretty unfamiliar with 8051 microcontrollers and assembly language.

```
 ; This code places some values into RAM at
    ; addresses 0x30 through 0x39:
    MOV R0, #0x30
    MOV R1, #0
    MOV R2, #10
    MOV R3, #0
    MOV A, #144
    MOV B, #253
    again:
    MUL AB
    ADD A,B
    DEC B
    MOV @R0,A
    ADD A,R2
    XRL B,#11011010b
    INC R0
    DJNZ R2, again
    CLR C

; Complete this program by writing code below
; that looks at the values in RAM at addresses 0x30 through 0x39,
; and determines the number of odd values and the number of even
; values.  Your code should store at address 0x40 the number 
; of even values found and at address 0x41 the number of odd 
; values found.
MOV R1, #0x30
MOV R2, #0
MOV R3, #0
MOV R4, #10
MOV R5, #0x40
MOV R6, #0x41
Loop:
MOV A,@R1
ANL A, #00000001b
INC R1
JZ even
INC R2
JMP after
even:
INC R3
after:
DJNZ R4,Loop

Loop2:;Not sure if this second loop is needed
; to output the number of evens and odds in #0x40 and #0x41 
MOV A,R1
MOV A,R5
DJNZ R4,Loop2
```

Comment: Your odd/even loop makes sense. It's unclear why you want a loop at the end. Just store `R3` into `0x40` and `R2` into `0x41`.

Comment: Ok so would I do something like this: MOV R3, @R5?

Comment: Logically yes, but `@R5` is not a valid addressing mode. You can just do `MOV 0x40, R3` directly.

Comment: Thanks I got it! I was unclear if I could just store the values in the literal register, but it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic to count the evens and odds is sound, but you can improve the code for smaller footprint and faster execution.

- The loop that initialized the array ends with the `R0` register pointing at 3Ah. You can use this fact and traverse the array from the end to the start. This will save you from having to setup a pointer.
- Instead of first counting in a couple of registers and then storing those to memory, you can directly count in memory.
- The `JMP after` will use 2 cycles, but you can replace it by a compensating `DEC 40h` that will only use 1 cycle.

```
                   ; R0 == #3Ah
  MOV  40h, #0     ; Number of evens
  MOV  41h, #0     ; Number of odds
  MOV  R2, #10
Loop:
  DEC  R0          ; Pre-decrement to work backwards
  MOV  A, @R0
  ANL  A, #00000001b
  JZ   even
odd:
  INC  41h
  DEC  40h
even:
  INC  40h
  DJNZ R2, Loop
```

### Even better

This is based on the fact that the sum of the evens and the odds has to be 10.

```
                   ; R0 == #3Ah
  MOV  40h, #0     ; Number of evens
  MOV  R2, #10
  MOV  41h, R2     ; Number of odds
Loop:
  DEC  R0          ; Pre-decrement to work backwards
  MOV  A, @R0
  ANL  A, #00000001b
  JNZ  odd
even:
  INC  40h
  DEC  41h
odd:
  DJNZ R2, Loop
```